# How to make a fifo in C?

Tags: linux, c, fifo

I have to use `mkfifo` in my C program in Ubuntu. But I have an error when I compile: `no such file or directory` .

I think the problem because I have not set the `panel_fifo` environment variables. But I don't khow how could I do this.

Here is my code I use to test this method:

```
char *myfifo="./sock/myfifo";

if (mkfifo(myfifo,0777)<0)
perror("can't make it");

if (fd=open(myfifo,O_WRONLY)<0)
 perror("can't open it");
```

I compile this with:

`gcc gh.c -o gh`

When I run, I get this error message:

```
can't make it:no such file or directory
can't open it:no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please include your C program and the command with what you want to compile it. And the _full_ error message, too. But the profile (if you think to your login shell init script) isn't written in C, it is in (most cases) bash. The function of `panel_fifo` is to me unclear.

Comment: I wrote above my code
thank you for helping

Comment: The most probable cause is that the sock directory doesn't exist.

Comment: The directory exists

i have changed it many .. but the same problem

Comment: Are you sure this directory exists *as the sub-directory in which you run your compiled binary*? What happens when you use absolute path?

Comment: yes the directory exists.
and i have new file "myfifo" in it when i run the program
but i cann't open it because i have not the suitable program

Comment: So you can see the created fifo in an `ls`?

Comment: yes i can see it. it is an embarrassing  thing

Comment: It is very ridiculous, this code you wrote should work. Maybe a `strace` could help. I don't have more idea, maybe others will have. Good luck!

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc 5.1.0.

Comment: I search in web and find some have the same problem.
some have solved it by adding pane_fifo environment variable using profile script or they set it explicity in the panel script.
but for me i don't know how i do that

Comment: so what I have to do?

Comment: Googling for "pane_fifo" or "panel_fifo" doesn't get any result seeming relevant, this whole "panel" thing I simply don't understand, and the `mkfifo()` C api call isn't affected by any environment variable. You have a trivial C code which looks perfectly okay. Write more about the specific problem, what is this whole "panel" thing, probably there lies the cause. But this is highly extraordinary.

Comment: Here is the website I have talked about. The same problem and the solution https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186349

Comment: 1: C and Linux are case sensitive, "panel_fifo" and "PANEL_FIFO" are different strings. 2: This link describes a problem specific to bspwm, PANEL_FIFO is used by this window manager and not by your C code.

Comment: I am so sorry this is my first steps in this way .. So my problem happens because the wrong directory??!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the directory sock doesn't exist.

In a terminal:

```
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ ls
t2.c
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ cat t2.c 
#include <fcntl.h>

main() {

int fd;
char *myfifo="./sock/myfifo";

if (mkfifo(myfifo,0777)<0)
  perror("can't make it");

if (fd=open(myfifo,O_WRONLY)<0)
  perror("can't open it");

}
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ cc t2.c
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ ./a.out 
can't make it: No such file or directory
can't open it: No such file or directory
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ mkdir sock
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ ./a.out
```

Note the program hasn't completed, but your fifo does exist.

Now in a second terminal, put a string into the fifo

```
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ ls -l sock/
total 0
prwxrwxr-x 1 christian christian 0 May 27 06:45 myfifo
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ echo abc >sock/myfifo
```

Note echo also is suspended

Now in a third terminal, read from the fifo

```
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$ cat sock/myfifo 
abc
christian@fujiu1404:~/tmp/t2$
```

Note now all programs complete and exit (in all terminals)

Comment: Wahoo That it.. Thank you very mach

Comment: Ok..Is there any way to include all this steps in my code?!?

Comment: I've shown you how to see what's going on by using cat and echo on different terminals. Now read `man 3 mkfifo` and read about blocking, permissions etc. you might want to read further `man fifo` You are going to have two programs at least, a reader and a writer. I think it's over to you now, since what to write depends on what you want it to do. So that might be a different (new) question.

Comment: Sorry but I am New in this.. How can I mark it as solved..  I am using android app

Comment: I use a web browser, where one hit's a tick by the votes answered, in addition, on the right column there are related answers, take a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870549/fifos-implementation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You try

```
myfifo("./sock/myfifo", ...)
```

You get

> no such file or directory

which is `ENOENT`.

You then want to look up the relevant documentation and find the following in [`man 3 mkfifo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkfifo.3.html):

> **ERRORS**
>
> [...]
>
> **ENOENT** A directory component in pathname does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link.

From all this one could conculde `./sock` does not exist.